# Bug in PostgreSQL locking mechanism or misunderstanding of the mechanism

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking

We encountered an issue with PostgreSQL 9.0.12 locking mechanism.

This is our minimal code to reproduce the issue:

Scenario

```
Transaction 1      Transaction 2
BEGIN              BEGIN
......             select trees for update;                
update apples;      
--passes
update apples;    
-- stuck!
```

reproduce code:
If you want to try it in your PostgreSQL - here is a code you can copy/paste.

I have a following db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE trees (
    id       integer primary key
);

create table apples (
    id       integer primary key,
    tree_id  integer references trees(id)
);

insert into trees values(1);
insert into apples values(1,1);
```

open two psql shells:

on shell 1:

```
BEGIN;
    SELECT id FROM trees WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

on shell 2:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;
```

The second update of apples will stuck and it seems that the porcess of shell 2 is wating on the transaction of shell 1 to finish.

```
relname  |transactionid|procpid|mode              |substr                                    |       age      |procpid
-----------+-------------+-------+------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+-------
           |             | 4911  | ExclusiveLock    | <IDLE> in transaction                    | 00:05:42.718051|4911
           |   190839904 | 4911  | ExclusiveLock    | <IDLE> in transaction                    | 00:05:42.718051|4911
trees      |             | 4911  | RowShareLock     | <IDLE> in transaction                    | 00:05:42.718051|4911
           |             | 5111  | ExclusiveLock    | UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  | 00:05:21.67203 |5111
           |   190839905 | 5111  | ExclusiveLock    | UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  | 00:05:21.67203 |5111
apples_pkey|             | 5111  | RowExclusiveLock | UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  | 00:05:21.67203 |5111
apples     |             | 5111  | RowExclusiveLock | UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  | 00:05:21.67203 |5111
trees      |             | 5111  | RowShareLock     | UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  | 00:05:21.67203 |5111
trees      |             | 5111  | ShareLock        | UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  | 00:05:21.67203 |5111
           |             | 2369  | ExclusiveLock    | <IDLE> in transaction                    | 00:00:00.199268|2369
           |             | 2369  | ExclusiveLock    | <IDLE> in transaction                    | 00:00:00.199268|2369
           |             | 5226  | ExclusiveLock    | select pg_class.relname,pg_locks.transac | 00:00:00       |5226
```

Have we misunderstood something or it is a bug in postgres?

Comment: typos(in first snippet): s/apple/apples/g; s/tree/trees/g` ?? Also(final snippet): terminal1 <--> terminal2 ??

Comment: This is probably better sent to the Postgres mailing list.

Comment: The first shell is done as soon as you do the `COMMIT`. The second shell tries to update a record which is in the process of being updated.

Comment: *First* you should at least [upgrade to the latest point release (9.0.17) as strongly advised by the Postgres developers.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) And test again. Or consider upgrading to the current release 9.3.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I could reproduce the behavior using 9.3.4 (although without committing the select from the first transaction) - the second transaction hangs on the second update, not the first update which *is* kind of weird

Comment: The `: ` in `UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1:` is just a typo then?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the reproduce code.

Comment: That's pretty odd. Please raise this on `pgsql-bugs@postgresql.org`. I don't see any reason why, once the first update has the row lock, the second update has any reason to wait on any other tx.

Comment: In case you want the first transaction to go through quickly to reduce locking issue, please see if the foreign key is indexed. In case it is not, create an index and the first transaction may finish quickly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no bug, and I don't think you're misunderstanding anything; you're just missing a couple of pieces of the puzzle.

Foreign keys are implemented internally using row-level locking; starting from Postgres 8.1 and up to 9.2, whenever you update the referencing table (`apples` in this case), a query is fired that does `SELECT FOR SHARE` on the referenced table (`trees`).  So that `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in the first transaction blocks the `SELECT FOR SHARE` of the referential integrity for the second transaction.  This is what causes the block in the second command.

Now I hear you yell, “Wait!  How come it blocks on the second command and not the first?  The explanation is simple, really -- that's just because there is a simple optimization that skips the internal `SELECT FOR SHARE` when the key is not being modified.  However, this is simplistic in that if you update a tuple a second time, this optimization will not fire because it's harder to track down the original values.  Hence the blockage.

You might also be wondering why I said this is up to 9.2 --- what's with 9.3?  The main difference there is that in 9.3 it uses `SELECT FOR KEY SHARE`, which is a new, lighter lock level; it allows for better concurrency.  If you try your example in 9.3 and also change the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to `SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE` (which is a lighter mode than `SELECT FOR UPDATE` that says you are maybe going to update the tuple, but you promise to not modify the primary key and promise not to delete it), you should see it doesn't block.  (Also, you can try an UPDATE on the referenced row and if you don't modify the primary key, then it will also not block.)

This 9.3 stuff was introduced by a patch by yours truly as http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=0ac5ad5134f2769ccbaefec73844f8504c4d6182 and I think it was a pretty cool hack (The commit message has some more details, if you care about that sort of stuff).  But beware, do not use versions prior to 9.3.4 because that patch was so hugely complex that a few serious bugs went unnoticed and we only fixed recently.

Comment: Thanks,
We are having hard time to workaround it in our application.
It leads us to deadlock.

script to reproduce the deadlock:
shell 1:  
    BEGIN;  
    SELECT id FROM trees WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;  
    --> then move to shell 2.  
    UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  
    --> deadlock  
on shell 2:  
    BEGIN;  
    UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  
    UPDATE apples SET id = id WHERE id = 1;  
    then return to shell 1  
Any tips how to avoid this deadlock?

Comment: `UPDATE set id=id` doesn't seem very reasonable. Are you really updating the value of the primary key? If so, nothing can help you.  And can you use FOR SHARE instead of FOR UPDATE in the first session?