# Postgresql UPDATE constrained column with same value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there perfomance impact (like redundant index lookups) when UPDATEing constrained (unique, FK) column with the same value?

Say, I've changed `field1` of my POJO, but UPDATE is done for all fields, like

```
UPDATE pojo SET field1=?, field2=?, field3=?, ... WHERE ...
```

(`field2` is defined as `UNIQUE` and `field3` is FK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are. PostgreSQL tries to optimize them out in some places, but support is a bit limited.

For one thing, it can cause [weird effects with locking and foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22606063/398670).

For another, it'll prevent `HOT` updates of the row, forcing index updates where they might not otherwise be necessary.

While not generally an issue for unique key fields, you'll also force a re-write of out-of-line TOAST data if you update a TOASTed field to the same value, rather than leaving it out of the update entirely. This wastes space and disk I/O.

All in all, avoid such an update if you can. Update only fields you have actually changed.